# Firebase App not fetching data in slow internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app uses Firebase Realtime Database, Firestore, and Auth.

PROBLEM: I noticed when the wifi router is in "Blinking Orange Light Mode", my app cannot fetch data from Firebase but somehow other apps' internet works. I have other API, works fine when Firebase doesn't. When I turn off wifi or if I reset my wifi router, Firebase works flawlessly. But we cannot force users to reset or turn off their wifi.

Is there any configuration I am missing to get it work in slow internet connection?

Comment: Can you show some code of how your android app connect to FireBase? Maybe something in the connection part is messed up.